# Pre-render VueJs application issue with prerender-spa-plugin

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, prerender

I'm using prerender-spa-plugin to pre-render my vueJs application for sake of SEO.
It seems to be working normally but I have an issue with Javascript (eg: OnClick, onSubmit) it didn't fire.

Any hint?

Comment: Looks like it's an active issue: https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin/issues/31

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I can't find a solution there